# reducer can't set props as null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

- To log in, I set token as token string 'randomTokenString' (I could set 'token' property using 'setToken' action.
- To log out, **I want to set the token as null.**

The problem is I can't set token when I log out. 
( console.log(action.payload) prints 'null' as expected. )

Here is a snippet of reducer

```
case SET_TOKEN:
      console.log('passing set token');
      console.log(action.payload); <- prints null as expected
      return { token: action.payload, errorMsg: '' };
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './auth_reducer';
import menu from './menu_reducer';
export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  menu
});
```

This is screen

```
_doLogOut = () => {
    // remove token, close modal, set all props null.
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
    this.props.setToken(null);
    console.log(this.props.token); <- here it prints 'randomTokenString' (not null)
    if ( this.props.token == undefined || _.isNull(this.props.token) ) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    }
  }

function mapStateToProps({ auth: { token }, menu:{ username, bio }}) {
  return {
    token, username, bio
  }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MenuScreen);
```

This is action part

```
export const setToken = ( token ) => ({
  type: SET_TOKEN,
  payload: token
});
```

- Update:

I just found out if I press logout again, it navigates to 'Auth'. So reducer actually saved the props as null. So when I check if the props.token is null, the prop is not changed yet... Anyone can explain this??? So weird.

I think I should set a callback function for setToken().

Comment: If you change `this.props.setToken(null);` to `this.props.setToken('test');`, does it work?

Comment: Interesting... Yes!

Comment: I'm not sure why it can't set it to null. It's a simple code though..

Comment: just do `this.props.setToken();`

Comment: Could you show more of your reducer? And your `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: Sorry setToken() didn't work. :( It changes token as undefined only inside of reducer.

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry for late reply. I just edited the post. I posted action part and connect part

Comment: I just found out if I press logout again, it navigates to 'Auth'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redux actions is asynchronous, and after it has been 'reduced', the state changes and updates the props. So, the logic for navigating after call the action should be put in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const { navigation, token: newToken } = newProps;
  const { token: oldToken } = this.props;

  if (oldToken !== newToken && _.isNil(newToken)) {
    navigation.navigate('Auth');
  }
}
```

Notes: The lodash's `isNil` checks for both `undefined` and `null`